# How to display only 3 button per row using boostrap?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
form{


  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;

}


form .buttons{

 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 background-color: #ffffff00;
 cursor: pointer;

}

form .buttons img{

 width: 100%;

}

form button{

 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000000;

}
```

I'm a rookie in bootstrap for starter. The thing is I have ten buttons which contain image, but depending on an if statement, not all the button will be displayed. My problem is to display the remaining button 3 per row responsively using bootstrap or css.
I have used tables, flexbox, grid but it still can't do it.

```html
echo "</head>";
   echo"<body>";
  echo "<script src=\"../js/jquery.js\"></script>";
  echo "<form  action='../include/newHealthScore.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='input1' id='input1' value='' hidden='true'>
  <input type='text' name='input2' id='input2' value='' hidden='true'>
  <input type='text' name='input3' id='input3' value='' hidden='true'>";
  echo "<div class = 'container'>";
  echo "<div class = 'col-md-12'>";
  echo "<div class=\"jumbotron jumbotron-fluid\">
    <div class=\"container\"  align=\"center\">
      <h1 class=\"display-4\">Choose a maximum of 3 options</h1>
      <p class=\"lead\" align=\"justify\">Depending on your health score calculated, some option will be available for you to choose. Each option will give you points so as to increase your overall health score. Point for blood pressure is displayed in pink. Point for LDL is displayed in yellow. Point for HDL is displayed in blue. Point for HbA1c is displayed in orange. Point for waist is displayed in green. Finally point for whether you smoke or not is displayed in brown.</p>
    </div>
  </div>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class = 'container'>";
  echo "<div class='d-inline-flex'>";
  if( $bPressure < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity1' type='button'><img src='../img/salt.png'></button><br/>";
  }
  if($bPressure < 10 || $ldl < 10 || $hdl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity2' type='button' ><img src='../img/balancemeal.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if ($bPressure < 10 || $ldl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity3' type='button'><img src='../img/rawveg.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($hdl < 10 || $ldl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity4' type='button'><img src='../img/fat.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($ldl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity5' type='button'><img src='../img/sugar.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }

  if($bPressure < 10 || $hdl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity6' type='button'><img src='../img/alcohol.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($bPressure < 10 || $ldl < 10 || $hdl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $waist < 10 || $smoke < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity7' type='button'><img src='../img/30min.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($bPressure < 10 || $ldl < 10 || $hdl < 10 || $hba1c < 10 || $smoke < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity8' type='button'><img src='../img/walk303.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($smoke < 10)
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity9' type='button'><img src='../img/smoking.png'></button><br/>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  if($takePill = "y")
  {
    echo "<div class=\"p-2\">";
    echo "<button class='buttons' value='activity10' type='button'><img src='../img/pills.png'></button>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  echo "<div class= 'd-flex justify-content-center'>";
  echo "<input class = 'btn btn-primary rounded-pill btm-lg btn-huge' type='submit' name='Submit' value = 'Submit'/>";
  echo "</div>";

  echo "</form>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";

  echo "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js\"></script>
  <script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js\" ></script>
  <script src=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js\" ></script>
";
  echo "</body>";
[enter image description here][1]
I found a way to do it. but now new problem arises. They are glued together and now i can't put a space between them. Also they do not fill up the container.
Bellow is the new code

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: hi @Kevin - I suggest you try using tables with border=1 - that way when you adjust your code you can see the effect on layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by using `grid system of Bootstrap`. You can have div with `container` and if you want to have a full-width container the div has to have a `container-fluid` class  then for each line of buttons you need make a div with a class of `row` and put your button -in this case three buttons- in every row inside divs with `col` classes and give a css class called `btn-block` to every button like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Having three buttons per row in Bootstrap 4.4.1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1 btn-block">btn 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1 btn-block">btn 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1 btn-block">btn 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1 btn-block">btn 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1 btn-block">btn 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1 btn-block">btn 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in case you need a `btn-group` you can use them instead of normal btn and you can read more about it from related [Bootstrap documentation for btn-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/button-group/).

Comment: will it remain as in the snippet as aboive? As one button in the same div may not appear if  the if statement does not return true.

Comment: i tried your solution. It did puts 3 item on same row but the distance between the buttons increases and makes the rows to be display not in an orderly fashion like in your code above. To be precised each row the size of the button increases and i dont know why. Buttons on the second row is bigger than its predecessor.

Comment: I accidentally used align-items-center css class in the first row class. If you just copied my code please do it again I just modified it for you and see if the problem gets solved.

Comment: Please notice that I used some classes like "m-2" or "m-1". These classes change the margin of each element they're used in the class list of that element. We can use m-0 to m-5 in Bootstrap to set or increase margin of an element. We can also use mb-0 to mb-5 for margin-bottom plus we can use margin for other directions like mt-* for margin-top and mr-* for margin-right and ml-* for margin-left. So you can change margin of buttons or rows as much as you want... for example change m-1 of button's classes to ml-1 or m-2 and stuff like this.

Comment: I update the code as you said. Thanks for your kind help. It corrected my problem to some extends. Now the button are no more randomly arranged.